# Keras timeseriesgenerator: how to predict multiple data points in one step?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I have meteorological data that looks like this:

```
DateIdx               winddir   windspeed   hum         press       temp
2017-04-17 00:00:00   0.369397  0.155039    0.386792    0.196721    0.238889
2017-04-17 00:15:00   0.363214  0.147287    0.429245    0.196721    0.233333
2017-04-17 00:30:00   0.357032  0.139535    0.471698    0.196721    0.227778
2017-04-17 00:45:00   0.323029  0.127907    0.429245    0.204918    0.219444
2017-04-17 01:00:00   0.347759  0.116279    0.386792    0.213115    0.211111
2017-04-17 01:15:00   0.346213  0.127907    0.476415    0.204918    0.169444
2017-04-17 01:30:00   0.259660  0.139535    0.566038    0.196721    0.127778
2017-04-17 01:45:00   0.205564  0.073643    0.523585    0.172131    0.091667
2017-04-17 02:00:00   0.157650  0.007752    0.481132    0.147541    0.055556
2017-04-17 02:15:00   0.122101  0.003876    0.476415    0.122951    0.091667
```

My aim: to use the keras timeseriesgenerator (`from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator`) to train and predict multiple data points (multiple rows) at once, e.g. not to do

```
[input X]                  | [targets y]
[dp1, dp2, dp3, dp4, dp5]  | [dp6]
[dp2, dp3, dp4, dp5, dp6]  | [dp7]
[dp3, dp4, dp5, dp6, dp7]  | [dp8]
                          ...
```

but to do

```
[input X]                  | [targets y]
[dp1, dp2, dp3, dp4, dp5]  | [dp6, dp7, dp8]
[dp2, dp3, dp4, dp5, dp6]  | [dp7, dp8, dp9]
[dp3, dp4, dp5, dp6, dp7]  | [dp8, dp9, dp10]
                          ...
```

I can achieve the top kind of predictions with

```
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(
    X,
    X,
    length=5,
    sampling_rate=1,
    stride=1,
    start_index=0,
    end_index=None,
    shuffle=False,
    reverse=False,
    batch_size=1,
)
```

, but I haven't figured out how I can tweak the generator options for the second kind of predictions.

Is there an easy way to achieve the desired prediction window of 3 data points with the timeseriesgenerator? If not, can you suggest me some code to bin my predictions `y` to achieve the task? Tnx

Comment: Its a little bit unclear what you want here. Does your model need y targets with three entries to be trained, or is your model already trained and you just want to call predict on three different windows? If its the first one, you will need to change the target input to the generator to suit the output shape of your model. Could you include those details in your question?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez I confirm that I want the first case you mention - to train and later predict in both cases with targets `[dp_N, dp_N+1, dp_N+2]` in a single step. I know I can achieve this without the `TimeseriesGenerator`, if I create myself with additional code a suitable target array `y`. But I wonder if I could use for that task `TimeseriesGenerator`, because it is so convenient! Do you have any advice or alternatively a simple preprocessing code for creating the array `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do with the TimeSeries generator is to change the target entry. Concretely, since you want to predict the next thee timesteps, your target should be something of the form

```
               target=np.concatenate((np.roll(X, -1, axis=0),
                                      np.roll(X, -2, axis=0),
                                      np.roll(X, -3, axis=0)
                                      ),axis=1)
```

The roll will shift your rows downward, you should probably throw away the last two rows of the target.
Therefore when you define your generator , you can now use the `target` object as a parameter:

```
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(
    X,
    target,
    length=5,
    sampling_rate=1,
    stride=1,
    start_index=0,
    end_index=None,
    shuffle=False,
    reverse=False,
    batch_size=1,
)
```

Note that now, when you do call `model.fit` it expect output shaped like 3*dim_col*X, so your model architecture and/or loss function needs to account for this, you should therefore change the output dim of your last layer directly, or combine 3 models    using `layer.concatenate([model_timeplus1,model_timeplus2,model_timeplus3], axis=-1)`
if you choose a shared weight model (the  three predicted values generated by one single nn `model_timeplus1`):

```
layer.concatenate([model_timeplus1,model_timeplus1,model_timeplus3], axis=-1)
```

It is equivalent to an unrolled [recursive neural network](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/teaching/cs-230/cheatsheet-recurrent-neural-networks).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out as soon as possible (sunday or Monday) and accept it as answer if it does the job!

Comment: Thanks, it seemed that your suggestion worked when I used as a taget `y = np.stack((np.roll(X, 0, axis=0), np.roll(X, -1, axis=0), np.roll(X, -2, axis=0)),axis=1)`. But I am now stuck at the remark you made - `X` and `y` have different shapes ((5264, 12) and (5264,3,12)) and the model throws an error. Can you elaborate on the use of `layer.concatenate` or provide me with a minimal working model architecture?

Comment: they will have different shapes since an element from the predict has 3 times as many dimensions as the input. if  you want the target to have shape (5264, 3*12) you 
 can do `np.concatenate(np.roll(X, -1, axis=0), np.roll(X, -2, axis=0),
                np.roll(X, -3, axis=0), axis=1)` instead of stack. your model training will now require your model output layer to have shape (3*12,) instead of (12,) which is why i suggested layer.concatenate (i will edit answer to show an example)

Comment: For future readers: an architecture that would work with this input-output shapes can also be created with the help of max pooling and `RepeatVector`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62917566/5838180