# Tensorflow keras timeseries prediction with X and y having different shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, regression

I am trying to do time series prediction with tensorflow and keras with `X` and `y` having different dimensions:

```
X.shape = (5000, 12)
y.shape = (5000, 3, 12)
```

When I do the following

```
n_input = 7
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(X, y, length=n_input, batch_size=1)

for i in range(5):
    x_, y_ = generator[i]
    print(x_.shape)
    print(y_.shape)
```

I get as desired the output

```
(1, 7, 12)
(1, 3, 12)
(1, 7, 12)
(1, 3, 12)
...
```

This is because my data is meteorological, I have 5000 days, for training in the array `X` I use a sliding window of 7 days, with each day containing 12 features (air pressure, temperature, humidity a.o.). And in the target array `y` I have sliding windows of 3 days, trying to predict the next 3 days to each window of 7 days.

But then when I try to fit the model I get an error due to the mismatch in the shape of the `X` and `y` arrays:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(None, 12)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=3).history

ValueError: A target array with shape (1, 3, 12) was passed for an output of shape (None, 1) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

So is there a way to adjust the architecture for the mismatch in the dimensions? Or is there a way to reshape `X` and `y` to make them work with this architecture? I tried the late reshaping `X` into `(5000, 7, 12)`, but this gave also a dimensionality error. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your generator is correct... it's your network that doesn't work.

you don't handle the dimensionality correctly. you are dealing with sequences so you need to impose `return_sequences=True` in your LSTM cells. your input has 7 timesteps while your output has 3 timesteps, you have to pass from 7 to 3 (you can do it with pooling and so on).

below a dummy example. I don't use a pooling operation but simply select a part of the sequence in order to get an output of 3 timesteps

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (5000, 12))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, (5000, 3, 12))

n_input = 7
generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(X, y, length=n_input, batch_size=32)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_input, 12)))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-3:,:]))
model.add(Dense(12))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.summary()

model.fit(generator, epochs=2)
```

here an example with pooling operation

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_input, 12)))
model.add(MaxPool1D(2)) # also AvgPool1D is ok
model.add(Dense(12))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.summary()
model.fit(generator, epochs=2)
```

here an example with return_sequences=False and repeat vector

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(n_input, 12)))
model.add(RepeatVector(3))
model.add(Dense(12))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.summary()
model.fit(generator, epochs=2)
```

Comment: Thanks, if you would provide a working version with "pooling and so on" I can accept you answer as the correct one. I guess the example you provide would, for the sake of functionality, ignore some of the training data

Comment: @NeStack I edited the answer by adding other examples... give a trial to all an try to play also with your network structure. don't forget to upvote and accept as answer ;-)

Comment: @NeStack let me know if there are problems

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked indeed! I delayed my response, because I was looking into some next questions to maybe ask: what is the difference between `MaxPool1D`, `AvgPool1D`, `RepeatVector`; what should be `N` in `model.add(LSTM(N)`; should I add dropout and more dense layers and most importantly what would be a good state-of-the-art architecture to apply for my time series prediction. So, it's all questions out of the scope of what I asked initially, but would help me to achieve my prediction task. So, if you want give your opinion to them :)

Comment: The choice of parameters, layer depth, structure are choices related to your data. the best thing to do is to make some tuning using a valuable validation schema. there are state of art model/strucure like wavenet or inception for time series, you can find them easily on internet

Answer (score 1):

Your final (fully connected) layer's shape is (None, 1) and your output's shape is (None, 3, 12). Output shapes of data and the network have to match.

I would use [the Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) and create 3 separate Dense layers and concatenate them. Like this:

```
inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(7, 12))
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)(inp)

y1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12)(x)
y2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12)(x)
y3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12)(x)

y1 = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(y1, axis=1)
y2 = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(y2, axis=1)
y3 = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(y3, axis=1)

output = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([y1, y2, y3])

mdl = tf.keras.Model(inp, output)
mdl.summary()
```

Returned:
[Model Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nxig.png)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I accepted Marco's answer, because his looked more intuitive for my skill level and is easier to implement. Anyways, I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: Thanks, it was my first answer! I don't have experience with LTSM's, I just thought about fixing the error that I saw. I think his answer makes more sense with your case too.